# How to fetch metrics for Memory Usage, CPU utilization and Render time in k6?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, k6

I am new to performance testing and k6 so please be kind. I am figuring out a way to find out the total memory used for a particular test, I tried a lot but didn't find any way.
Also I want to fetch the time it takes to render a page after a certain event.

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check } from 'k6';

export default function () {
  const response = http.get('https://example.com');
  const renderTime = response.timings.duration - response.timings.waiting;
  check(renderTime, {
    'Render time is less than 1s': (renderTime) => renderTime < 1000,
  });
}
```

Through above code I have been able to get the metric, but even though the metric itself shows time in milliseconds, the check always fails.
I would really appreciate if you could spot the issue or suggest a better way to get the render time, and suggest ways to fetch memory usage (if any).

Comment: "Render time" is something that happens in the browser, not on the HTTP level. You will need [xk6-browser](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-browser) for that. (Bundled as module with k6 0.43). (I'd also avoid using the name of an existing variable for the lambda parameter)

Comment: @knittl Thank you, I rectified my mistake of lambda parameter. Can you also suggest ways to create "render time" metric for xk6 browser?

Comment: You will have to check if xk6-browser provides such a metric. The [docs](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-browser/) list several metrics, such as `browser_first_contentful_paint`, `browser_first_paint`, and `browser_loaded`. All browser metrics are listed at https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-browser/get-started/browser-metrics/